# Is there an example of a sentient plant-based life form in any of the major book/movie/TV SciFi franchises?

Tags: sentience

***UPDATE:** Please note that the question was already answered perfectly - I am not looking for additional examples*

---

I remember that there was a sentient life form **evoloved from plants** in Star Control 2 game ([Supox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Control_races#Supox)).

Is there an example of such a life form in the major well known SciFi works/franchises?

Please note that it must be

- directly evolved from plants. E.g. Endervers' fathertrees on Lusitania don't count - they are a result of genetic messing by Descolada virus.
- Sci-Fi works (e.g. magical trees - ala Whomping Willow in Harry Potter don't count, neither do the Arda's Ents)
- Clearly sentient (e.g. Triffids don't count IMHO since I don't think they are clearly proven to be fully sentient in the books, although I could be wrong).
- Preferbly, though not required, an actual species, as opposed to a single Yggdrasil (well, I am not sure if Yggdrasil is sentient anyway, and it's not Sci-Fi to boot)

Comment: Please note that someone provided a great example from a TV show. I would love to also have an example from a SciFi book, if exists, in addition to that.

Comment: Yddrasill is totally Sci-Fi. It is a treeship in Hyperion by Dan Simmons.

Comment: @Dima - Sorry, IMHO Hyperion treeships don't count. From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperion_Cantos#Treeship):"Living trees (related to Dyson trees) " and "A Dyson tree is a hypothetical **genetically-engineered** plant, (perhaps resembling a tree) capable of growing in a comet, suggested by the physicist Freeman Dyson". So, they are not naturally evolved. Also, I don't think Hyperion is related to Norse Sagas, they simply took the tree name.

Comment: They are not sentient either.  But they are definitely Sci-Fi. :)

Comment: This feels like it is dangerously close to a list question with likely no one correct answer.

Comment: @Xantec - it's a "is there" yes/no question that has already be correctly answered with an example. I wasn't looking for an exhaustive list, as evidenced by "Is there an..." wording.

Comment: Touché. (spacing for 15 characters)

Comment: There was also Dr. Kineculus in _The Infinite Vulcan_ in _Star Trek_: The Animated Series.

Comment: Questions asking for lists of works having a particular topic are not welcome here. Please see the [FAQ] and the [meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/351#351) that triggered it. We have a [chatroom for this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1056/sf-topic-of-the-day), though it doesn't get many visitors (you would in fact be better off in the [main chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley)).

Comment: @Chad Because that's not what CW is for. CW isn't a way to “demote” bad questions, if it's been used for that in the past. Please read [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Farscape the [Delvians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delvian#Delvian) are humanoid walking plants.

Comment: +10 for making me read an article with the word "photogasms" at work :)

Comment: @DVK how do you not know about Delvians?

Comment: @DVK I thought Farscape was well known, is all.

Comment: @DVK, what are you doing on this site? ;)

Comment: @DVK, yep I know I, was joking, that you haven't watched  farscape :) (I was surprised you hadn't watched it given your profile)

Answer (score 7):

- The Kanten species in David Brin's Uplift series
- The Cactaceae in China Miéville's Bas-Lag series

And see also [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_extraterrestrials#Sentient_plants_.26_fungi), and [this TV Tropes one](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlantAliens).

Answer (score 7):

The plant from [Little Shop of Horrors](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091419/) is sentient.

Comment: This is a good example, although I'd say LSoH is just barely borderline SciFi.

Comment: @eidylon Do you know any giant talking plants, in science-fact??

Comment: LOL - no, just saying, people see LSoH, they don't generally consider themselves watching *science*-fiction, but just "fiction". I'm not saying I agree with that assessment, mind you.

Comment: @eidylon while that may be true, we're open to all forms of speculative fiction here!  Urban fantasy, alternate history, horror...don't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Vernor Vinge's "Zones of Thought" series, primarily in A Fire Upon The Deep, features aliens known as Skroderiders.  They're described as looking "like a small ornamental tree sitting in a six-wheeled cart" Baen Books has put the first 8 chapters on line: http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/0812515285/0812515285_toc.htm

Comment: In *The Children of the Sky* we are introduced to their vary much mobile and animal larval form. The Skroderiders are sessile, not vegetable.

Comment: Have only gotten about a third into Children... so I didn't know about their larval form, fwiw sessile does not rule out vegetable. "Plants may be categorized into two groups: petiolate plants wherein petioles are present and sessile plants in which petioles are absent." -from http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Sessile_plant

Answer (score 5):

There is the [Verdani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_of_The_Saga_of_Seven_Suns#Verdani) world-forest in The Saga of Seven Suns and the [Thorian](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Thorian) from Mass Effect.

Answer (score 1):

Avatar would seem to have an entire forest ecosystem that is sentient.

Answer (score 0):

I think the plant-girl Lyekka was my favorite character from [Lexx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx).

Now that you can actually watch lexx episodes in order instead of at the mercy of the broadcaster it's worth a try--it's a good show as long as you take it as it's meant to be taken (as in a tribute to 60's style sci-fi such as Barbarella)

Answer (score 0):

The Phylosians of Star Trek:TAS are sentient plants
http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Phylosian

The Zolfa-Thuran "Meglos" was described as a kind of sentient cactus
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meglos